How to make a canvas stay on top of the world?
My character has a Canvas above his head and I'm having a trouble on it mixing on another World objects.

How can I make the Canvas be displayed always on top of other world objects?
What I tried so far:
canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
canvas.sortingLayerName = "Default";
canvas.sortingOrder = 100;

Any idea?

dont make it world space, have it in screen space and work out where it should be based on world to screen coordinates?

If you want to keep the render mode as World Space, How about using a Stack camera- Overlay?

Set the Canvas Layer as something different.
Remove the Layer from base camera - culling mask
Make a new camera and set it as Overlay Stack from the main camera.
Set the new camera's culling mask - only the new layer.

